# Can't install php7 and phpmyadmin in centos 6.9 - adding repository failed

Tags: centos, yum, php, phpmyadmin, php7

I was trying to install php7 and phpmyadmin in centos 6.9.

I have added **epel-release** and **remi-release** repository for centos 6

`wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6.rpm epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm`

But when I run `yum repolist all` these repositories aren't listed in the list. Here is the [list](https://gist.github.com/aagontuk/a008a37a495f3675b2aab4f884f75b71)

Then I enabled repi-php70 repo to install php7

`yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70`

I have already installed PHP 5.3.3 in my system so i ran `yum update php` but yum reports:

`No Packages marked for Update`

Also ran `yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php70 install php php7 php70` but yum reports:

`Package php-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package php7 available.
No package php70 available.`

In case of **phpmyadmin** it should be found in epel-release repository. I have already added this repository so I ran `yum install phpmyadmin` but yum reports `No package phpmyadmin available`.

What am I missing here? How can I install PHP 7.0 and phpmyadmin? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does yum search epel-release not show the repository?

Comment: Actually it shows the repository. It reports:

"epel-release.noarch : Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux repository configuration"

Comment: Install that and then try to install phpmyadmin

Comment: I have installed that already!

$ yum install epel-release

`Package epel-release-6-8.noarch already installed and latest version`

This is the reason I am here!